Excel VBA: Loop Conditional Formatting of Chart through I chart series based on cell value
new to VBA here, but I have a simple line chart labeled series 1 to 7, X axis is categorical dates, ie each series has data on dates 8/12- 8/15. For each series, there is a cell in sheet 2 that pulls a "momentum" score, which can be anywhere from -4 to 10 (including decimals, hence using j as Double) which I would like to use to then conditionally format each series.
So logic is as this, check SubProcessSeries for Series 1, which correspond to cell D4, check all conditions > assign color, for Series 2, which corresponds to cell D5, check all conditions> Assign Color. Series 3> conditions> Assign Color.
I am not sure what I am doing wrong as I continue to through the type mismatch error under "worksheet_Calculate() for i.
Any ideas on how to do this?
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
  Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D4:D10")
  For i = 1 To 7
    ProcessSeries i, rng.Cells(i).Value
  Next
End Sub

Sub ProcessSeries(i As Integer, j As Double)
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart") _
      .SeriesCollection("Series" & i).Format.Line.ForeColor
        If j < -2 Then
            .RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' for values up to -2
        ElseIf j < -1 Then
            .RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0) ' for values from -2 to -1
        ElseIf j < 0 Then
            .RGB = RGB(200, 0, 0) ' for values from -1 to 0
        ElseIf j = 0 Then
            .RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' for value of 0
        ElseIf j < 1
            .RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0) ' for values from 0 to 1
        ElseIf j <= 2 Then
            .RGB = RGB(0, 200, 0) ' for values from 1 to 2
        Else
            .RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0) ' for values above 2
        End If
    End With
End Sub

I am stuck here, not really sure how to proceed: end goal is to conditionally format each series with its corresponding score in cells d4:d10 based on the RGB scales above.
Thank you

The code is missing a Then after the ElseIf j < 1. A ChartObject doesn't have a SeriesCollection property either, so likely missing a .Chart after .ChartObjects("Chart") as well. Fixing these two errors (and the missing variable declarations), my guess would be that rng.Cells(i).Value isn't a Double. Comment out the ProcessSeries call and instead Debug.Print i, VarType(rng.Cells(i).Value) perhaps to find the culprit.

If this VBA is in the code module for "Sheet1" then you can use Me in place of (eg) Sheets("Sheet1").  In a worksheet code module, Me refers to the corresponding worksheet.

thank you, a bit confused on one piece though, so the numbers can be whole numbers , ie -1, 1, 2, or they may be -1.222 1.3465 etc, is there a way to efficiently classify that j can be either?

j As Double works for either whole or fractional numbers, but a Type Mismatch suggests that you have nonnumeric value(s).

Maybe want to check that the cell value is a number before doing anything:
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    UpdateChartColors
End Sub

Sub UpdateChartColors()
    Dim sc As SeriesCollection, i As Long, m
    
    Set sc = Me.ChartObjects("Chart").Chart.SeriesCollection
    For i = 1 To 7
        m = Me.Range("D4:D10").Cells(i).Value
        If IsNumeric(m) Then
            sc("Series" & i).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = _
                    MomentumColor(CDbl(m))
        Else
            MsgBox "Momentum value '" & m & "' is not numeric"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

'Return an RGB color value for a given momentum value
Function MomentumColor(m As Double) As Long
    Select Case m
        Case Is < -2: MomentumColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Case Is < -1: MomentumColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        Case Is < 0: MomentumColor = RGB(200, 0, 0)
        Case 0: MomentumColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        Case Is < 1: MomentumColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        Case Is <= 2: MomentumColor = RGB(0, 200, 0)
        Case Is > 2: MomentumColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    End Select
End Function

